# SMC and the Milky Way

Tags: galaxy, magellanic-cloud

Do astronomers have any reason to believe that the Small Magellanic Cloud (SMC) collided with the Milky Way? If so, how do astronomers think about the concept of collision? Would a collision only happen when stars in one arbitrarily defined galactic area cross over into another? How would these areas in space be defined?